# dynamic data to Jquery code in ASP .Net Visual Studio

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, highcharts

I am a beginner in ASP .net Visual Studio. Following Highchart's tutorial of getting started, I have created a basic MVC application with a basic chart.
Now, I want to bind the data to the database model to generate dynamic data. How do I do that? I have written psuedocode below. Thank you for your help!

```
    <script>$(function () {
        $('#line').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [
 @foreach (var item in Model){ #psuedocode: pull out data from model so it display data as example below }
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Include some actual code that you tried, not just copypasta from highcharts demo page

Comment: I had some problems with this when I was trying to parse data and load them into Telerik DataViz controls in javascript, as well. Very much the same issue. I posted my solution that worked for me below, using what I guessed for your data nomenclature. You will probably have to tweak it to get it to work properly, and visual studio sometimes gives you script errors that are not actually errors when you are writing code in the `@:` section.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind when I post question on Stackoverflow next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `@:` operator to revert razor to text mode to iterate your model into json data.

```
        series: [
               @foreach (var item in Model)
               {
                  @:{ name: "@item.Name", data: [
                       @foreach(var d in item.data)
                       {
                          @:parseInt(@d.value),
                       }
                    },
               }
           ]
```

[Here is a link from Scott Guthrie talking about the `@:` and `@<text>` syntax.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need to get started!